# Объединить метки aws и amazon-web-services

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

С меткой [aws](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws) сейчас 42 вопроса.
С меткой [amazon-web-services](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) 7 вопросов.

Какую считать главной?

На en.so основной меткой считается [amazon-web-services](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте основной меткой сделаем [amazon-web-services](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services)

Аргументы "за":

- По названию тега хорошо понятно, о чём эта метка (выгодно по сравнению с сокращением aws, пусть и устоявшимся)
- Эта метка является основной на en.so

Comment: Не могли бы вы пояснить позицию, почему полное название, а не акроним? Думаю, это поможет нам принимать правильные решения быстро в будущем в аналогичных ситуациях.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Это хорошо потому что 1) может появиться в будущем такой же акроним для другого продукта (также этот довод действителен для коротких названий). 2) более понятно для тех, кто с этим не сталкивается часто. Быстрей понять что же это такое, чем гуглить акроним или короткое название.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky По поводу аналогичных ситуаций создал [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7030/220571).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Синонимизация успешно завершена.

Comment: Странно как-то. Не в ту сторону, видимо.

Comment: @alexolut, руководствовался принятым ответом и аргументами в комментах под ним)

Comment: Вот только вопросов по выбранной основной метке меньше. Выбирать оную только из-за en SO - ну такое. Я думал, мы метки выбираем по тому, как они используются...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня основная показывает [tag:aws], разве об этом принятый ответ?

Comment: @alexolut при открытии вашей ссылки открывается amazon-web-services, о чём вы? о_О

Comment: @Suvitruf очень [странная ситуация](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCngR.jpg). Вероятно, как обычно, виноват <s>PashaPash</s> кэш.

Comment: Действительно O:

Comment: @Suvitruf но может быть и Юный модератор :)

Answer (score -3):

Что-то не припомню, чтоб кто-то употреблял amazon web services. Почти всегда это просто aws. Принятое сокращение.

Не важно, что там на en SO, но у нас, мне кажется, лучше [aws](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws) сделать основной.

Comment: Чем лучше? Крткст — сстр тлнт? Синонимизацией можно сделать так, что при вводе короткой будет отображаться длинная и говорящая метка, а не краткая аббревиатура.

Comment: @alexolut например, тем, что можно будет удобно создавать теги типо [tag:aws-cloudfront], [tag:aws-s3] и т.п.

Comment: их можно создавать и при длинной основной метке. Основная длинная, вспомогательные — с аббревиатурой.

Comment: @alexolut, хотя бы по соотношению 42:7 при их использовании на вопросах.

Comment: @Qwertiy после драки кулаками не машут.

Comment: @alexolut почему же. Если синонимизация оказалась неправильная, то почему бы не поменять?

Comment: @alexolut, ну так можно и поменять.

Comment: @Suvitruf синомизация правильная, но сделалась как-то криво, метки не подменились должным образом.

Comment: @alexolut правильная, потому что так на en SO? Или потому что за эту метку проголосовало большинство (при этом, которые эту метку даже не используют) ? (:

Comment: @Suvitruf и то, и другое, и третье (из комментов г-на Овчинникова).