# Синонимизировать [android-intent] и [intent]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать [android-intent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent) и [intent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent). Основной как и на en SO сделать [android-intent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent).

Судя по [поиску](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent+-android) метка [intent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent) употребляется только в контексте Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как участник топ 1-2 по указанным меткам и по метке [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) предложение поддерживаю и, как модератор, немедленно утверждаю)

Comment: Что-то метки странно применились. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent У вопросов метка [tag:intent] ведь должна была поменяться на [tag:android-intent]?

Comment: c aws похожая проблема была https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7009/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-aws-%d0%b8-amazon-web-services/7288#comment29722_7288

Comment: Хм... Я просто через инструментарий модератора синоним утверждаю во всех случаях. Может какой-то баг в движке или проблемы кэша. Может @Nicolas Chabanovsky получится призвать и он что-то скажет?

Comment: PashaPash говорит, что нужно объединять, а не синонимизировать. Эти метки он поправил, в будущем будут писать в вопросе про объединение)

Comment: @Suvitruf, а, ОК)