# Синонимизировать метки или объединять? Объединять и синонимизировать! Но это не точно

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

В этих вопросах просили синонимизировать метки:

- [Синонимизировать [android-intent] и [intent]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7302/15479)
- [Объединить метки aws и amazon-web-services](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7009/15479)

Их синонимизировали, но не объединили. Позже уже PashaPash объединил. Если следовать ответам с en So "[What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/260198)" и "[Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119377/260198)", то:

1. Синонимизация не трогает текущие вопросы.
2. Объединение меток затрагивает старые вопросы, но новые вопросы всё ещё можно создавать с указанием старого тега.
3. При объединении меток есть возможность сделать их синонимами.

Насколько я могу судить, не все понимают, как это работает.

Объединять, но не синонимизировать, имеет смысл, если, к примеру, нужно переименовать метку.

Так что (это больше для модераторов): **большая часть запросов на синонимизацию на самом деле на объединение + синонимизацию**.

Comment: А можешь перевести ответ для https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6583/178988?

Comment: @Qwertiy сюда как ответ или в твой тред? На выходных посмотрю.

Comment: А куда больше подходит? А то я его только просматривал, но внимательно не читал. Вообще, подозреваю, что в твой он больше подойдёт, как более широкий, а у меня более точечный вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy готово.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!

Comment: @Suvitruf На мой взгляд, вопрос Qwerity более общий и выглядит более каноничным, поэтому предлагаю перенести ваш классный ответ туда. В данном же вопросе слишком много специфики, которую со временем могут разрешить и добавить [meta-tag:статус-завершено]. Поэтому не соглашусь, что это дубликаты.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov в принципе, дельное предложение. Перенёс.